# Equal padding around horizontal list of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to set equal padding between elements set with `display: flex` and `justified-content`?

```
ul {
        background-color: #ddd;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    li.active a {
        background-color: #111;
        color: #fff;
    }

<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coconut</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coconut</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coconut</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kale</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/wEtNwj2Nhw)

It is about `background-color` of active link. I would like to have something like in this image: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1**

Allow for an equal distribution of free space among all list items and  center the text (as in the image).

Add this to your CSS:

```
li { flex: 1; text-align: center; }
```

**STEP 2**

Enable the anchor element (`a`) to extend the full width of its container (so the entire `li` is clickable).

Add this to your CSS:

```
li a { display: block; }
```

[**Revised Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/2ScnCegOEn)